# Time series on x-axis of pandas subplots/dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to create subplots from a pandas dataframe with time in hh:mm:ss on the x-axis.

It works without the subplots but I get the following error when I try and have 2 subplots AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'set_xticks'

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

```
ax = df[df.columns[6:8]].plot(figsize=(7,5), grid = True, legend = True, subplots=True, layout = (2,1), sharex = False)

ax[0].set_xticks(df.index[::60].flatten())
ax[0].set_xticklabels(df.Time[::60], rotation=90)

ax[1].set_xticks(df.index[::60].flatten())
ax[1].set_xticklabels(df.Time[::60], rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Add `ax = np.squeeze(ax)`

Comment: Or `ax = ax.ravel()`